# iOS 7 searchdisplaycontroller and tableview offset disagreeing offsets

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a tableview in a RectEdgeAll view controller and a search bar as its tableview header. When I start searching, the search bar animates and settles into the normal position at top of the screen but the tableview doesn't follow it, it remains in the same position before starting the search leaving a gap between both views. How do I make it animate along with the search bar?

I tried already updating the contentOffset of the tableview when search start but it didn't even moved.

Tried both ways the tableview and search bar: code and storyboard.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    //self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;


}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
}
```

Before Search:

[image]

After Search:

[image]

Comment: Check out this page http://myioscodingtips.blogspot.ca/2013/10/uisearchdisplaycontroller-in-ios6-ios7.html

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by adding

`[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;`

these two lines in viewDidLoad function.
If I use

```
 [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
```

to set the frame of table view and put those lines in viewdidappear function and my current viewcontroller has a navigationcontroller this tableview goes behind the navigationcontroller but if I put those lines in viewdidload tableview starts from just under the navigationcontroller. don't know why this happens